Create chart in ppt using python from excel data
I want to take data from 2 excel files and make a single chart from them and paste the chart as an interactive chart in a copy of a ppt template slide using python. I am using data frame to store the data.
I have tried this -
import pptx  
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
import pandas as pd
excelfile1 = pd.read_excel("1st.xlsx",sheet_name="sheet1")
excelfile2 = pd.read_excel("2nd.xlsx",sheet_name="sheet1")
df1 = excelfile1.iloc[177:183,20:23]
df2 = excelfile2.iloc[177:183,21:23]
df1.columns = ["Range","PDF (%)","CDF (%)"] 
df2.columns = ["PDF (%)","CDF (%)"] 
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print(df)
# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation("Template.pptx")
slide = prs.slides[10]

# define chart data ---------------------
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = df1["Range"]
chart_data.add_series('PDF %', df1["PDF (%)"])

# add chart to slide --------------------
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
cchart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)
# chart_data1 = CategoryChartData()
# chart_data1.categories = df1["Range"]
chart_data.add_series('CDF %', df1["CDF (%)"])

# add chart to slide --------------------
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)
prs.save('chart-01.pptx')

However, when I am running this code, I am getting this as output -
Output from code
Can you please guide me as to where I am going wrong?

You appear to be making 2 charts, not one.

@Martin Packer, please let me know how to combine the 2 charts

I wasn't familiar with this aspect of python-pptx but I have reasons to become so. So I did more or less what you did - but with data not coming from Pandas. The answer to your question is a second call to chart_data.add_series, instead of the second call to slide.shapes.add_chart. That got me two series on one chart - which is what I think you want.

@MartinPacker, can you please let me know how to add series of different types (one bar and one line) to same chart?

I don't know if you can.
